# Use a text file to search alternately or one by one in selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I cannot get the algorithm on how I can alternately search using a list of a name in my txt.file.
Bear with my English I hope I can explain it much better.
My txt file contains:

```
Busia Retail Supervisor Demo
Busia Retail Supervisor Demo
Butere RS Demo Account
Butere RS Demo Account
Byangabo RS Demo Account
Byangabo RS Demo Account
Dapaong RS Demo
Dawanau RS Demo
Delveaux RS Demo Account
```

My Code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
acc = open(r'C:\Users\IanJayloG\Desktop\Python Files\Ex_Files_Learning_Python\Exercise Files\Test\test3py.txt')
myacc = acc.read()

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\IanJayloG\Desktop\Python Files\Ex_Files_Learning_Python\Exercise Files\Test\Driver\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://ump.bboxx.co.uk/#/search")

for i in myacc:
    driver.find_element_by_name("filterText").send_keys(myacc) #Search tab
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/app-root/app-main-view/main/app-get/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[14]/div/button[2]/i").click() #submit button
```

The output that I want is to be able to alternately search one by one the list of the name in my file after clicking submit. 
Sorry for asking you guys this I already use my own initiative for these past few days I just cannot get it.

The result that I'm getting is infinite `Busia Retail Supervisor DemoBusia Retail Supervisor DemoButere RS Demo AccountButere RS Demo AccountByangabo RS Demo AccountByangabo RS Demo AccountDapaong RS DemoDawanau RS DemoDelveaux RS Demto AccountDivo RS Demo accounBusia Retail Supervisor DemoBusia Retail Supervisor DemoButere RS Demo AccountButere RS Demo AccountByangabo RS Demo AccountByangabo RS Demo AccountDapaong RS DemoDawanau RS DemoDelveaux RS Demo AccountDivo RS Demo account`

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJn7t.png)

Comment: Yes that's true

Answer (score 2):

The first issue is when using `acc.read()`, you get the whole text in one string. So the loop iterates on each letter. (add `print(i)` to check that).

You should better use `acc.readlines()`, where each line of the file will be added in a list.

Then you just need to `clear` the input field before sending a new sequence of text in the loop, but `send_keys` needs only one line, not the whole `myacc`:

```
myacc = acc.readlines()

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\IanJayloG\Desktop\Python Files\Ex_Files_Learning_Python\Exercise Files\Test\Driver\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://ump.bboxx.co.uk/#/search")

for words in myacc:
    driver.find_element_by_name("filterText").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_name("filterText").send_keys(words)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/app-root/app-main-view/main/app-get/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[14]/div/button[2]/i").click()
```

---

Note that the method `clear()` may be optional if the field is already reset after each query.

Here is the related doc : https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.clear

Comment: Hi @PRmoureu thank you for your reply but the result is still the same :(

Comment: @IanJayloGuinto I think you need to try it again and use ONLY this code. This code should NOT behave in exactly the same way as your code.

Comment: you're welcome! Don't forget to mark the solution as accepted on your questions, it makes people happy ;)  (and it's usefull for everybody)